# galaxy S3.. viewport meta tag doesns't work

Tags: android, viewport, galaxy

I'm currently working on the web app which use medium-dpi in viewport meta tag like the below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,
      width=device-width, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

When I test it on a galaxy S3 device, viewport seems not work correctly.

I saw this kind of thing in Android 4.0.2. In android 4.0.2, i heard android OS itself has bug that can't apply the viewport correctly.

Anybody has any idea??

Comment: I have this problem too, all the usual viewport settings are innefective, the page is zoomed out and text twice as small as on an iphone or htc wildfire s. Would love to resolve this.

Answer (score 5):

I actually found an important clue.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

" values less than (or equal to) 320 result in a value equal to the device-width "

So, Doing "Width=320", a typical setting it migrating from the IPhone, it does not seem to work.

Set it to 321, and it works!

Tested on galaxy s3, playbook, galaxy note

Comment: LOL! That's crazy design. Amusingly that page says 'if your web page is designed to be exactly 320 pixels wide, then you might want to specify that size for the viewport width' and then immediately warns you that a viewport of 320 pixels means 'device-width'...