# Foundation4 breakpoint for mobile not detected for high density devices

Tags: android, css, media-queries, zurb-foundation, breakpoint-sass

Specifically, when testing my site on a Samsung Galaxy SIII I'm seeing the styles defined for the desktop.

How do you get the phone to use the mobile styles (with a 320px width in mind) or to utilize 'hide-for-small' class etc?

Currently, on that phone (and I figure retina display devices too) you'll not see .hide-for-small or global css being applied, only media queries for larger (768px and above) viewports.

Does anyone have experience making high DPI devices, i.e: (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) work with Foundation4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you remembered to include the Viewport meta tag? The S3's viewport is [360x604](http://i-skool.co.uk/mobile-development/web-design-for-mobiles-and-tablets-viewport-sizes/), so if you're seeing styles for media queries greater than 360 on your portrait view, chances are you have your viewport misconfigured. I'd encourage the following viewport tag and `@viewport` directive (in your CSS):

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">`

`@viewport {
  zoom: 1;
}`

Also take a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532642/galaxy-s3-viewport-meta-tag-doesnst-work) on the viewport meta tag on the S3.